# Как управлять движением мобов в онлайн-игре?

Tags: разработка-игр, клиент-сервер, gameserver

У меня есть консольный сервер, и также есть подключаемые к серверу игроки-клиенты (unity игра).

Клиенты отправляют свои координаты на сервер (знаю что не безопасно). Сервер в свою очередь рассылает координаты игрока всем подключенным игрокам.

Но как быть с мобами?

Нужно, чтобы мобы двигались, обходя присутствующие в игре препятствия.

Но в связи с тем, что сервер не имеет данных об игровой локации, а является лишь посредником данных между игроками, как управлять движением мобов?

Как это реализовано в других онлайн-играх?

Возможно, мне необходимо всё же сделать сервер не консольным приложением, а полноценным подобием игры с полноценной игровой локацией? Но вряд-ли онлайн игры работают по такому принципу.

Нужно, чтобы все мобы у каждого клиента были на одинаковых координатах, то есть - синхронизированы. Поэтому, локально обрабатывать движение ботов на стороне каждого клиента по отдельности нельзя.
Должен быть один управляющий центр.

Мне важна не техническая составляющая вопроса, а больше логическая.

Как это должно быть реализовано?

Comment: Консольность сервера никак не связана с его возможностью симулировать игру и отдавать игрокам всю нужную им информацию.

Comment: Но ведь в консоли я не смогу отслеживать столкновение игроков с объектами, потому что на сервере не будет этих объектов. Единственный вариант - создать массив координат всех объектов. Вы говорите об этом способе?

Comment: Почему же на сервере не будет объектов? )) Вам надо определиться, если у вас авторитарный сервер (обычно так и бывает), то только он и знает обо всех объектах.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правило сервер хранит у себя все данные, включая игровую локацию, положение игроков, мобов и игровых предметов.

Он при этом вполне может быть консольным, то есть не выводить никакую графическую информацию о игровом мире.

Сервер рассылает всю эту информацию игрокам. Информацию о перемещении мобов сервер рассчитывает сам, а о перемещении игроков получает от самих игроков, и рассылает всё это остальным игрокам.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Герман! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как консольный сервер может хранить локацию? Не совсем понимаю. Вы имеете в виду, создать массив координат всех препятствий?

Comment: @LateNight, это сильно зависит от деталей реализации. Проще всего хранить в том же виде, что и у игроков. Но сервер хранит всю карту, а игрокам может отправляться лишь та часть, что видна с их позиции.